# R - Applying cforest to a dataset with no outcomes

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to build a random forest model using a genomic dataset that has 1000+ columns and 20 samples and has no outcomes.

I decided to generate an outcomes column with random true and false values. I am using this as my dependent variable. So when the model completes, I get both the predicted and actual outcomes (the ones generated by me and bound to the data frame). Does this technique work in predicting the values?

Here is an example using the iris data set:

```
irisDF <- iris
Iris_Rand_outcomes <- c()
for(i in 1:150){
  num <- runif(1, 0, 1)
  if(num > 2/3){
    Iris_Rand_outcomes <- c(Iris_Rand_outcomes, "setosa")
  }
  else if(num < 1/3){
    Iris_Rand_outcomes <- c(Iris_Rand_outcomes, "versicolor")
  }
  else{
    Iris_Rand_outcomes <- c(Iris_Rand_outcomes, "virginica")
  }
}
irisDF$Species <- as.factor(Iris_Rand_outcomes)

Iris.forest.cf <- cforest(formula =  Species ~ ., data = irisDF,
                     controls = cforest_control(mtry=4,ntree = 10000))

table(predict(Iris.forest.cf, OOB = F),irisDF$Species)
    tabIris <- as.data.frame(x = predict(Iris.forest.cf, OOB = F))
    tabIris <- cbind(tabIris, irisDF$Species)
colnames(tabIris) <- c("Predicted","Actual")
table(irisDF$Species)
tabIris
```

I am looking to see if cforest can find an underlying pattern in the data and maybe give me some prediction on this pattern.

I want to find the outcome of the data. Can the random forest see a pattern in the data and give me a prediction that can help me label (put them into classes) the samples? Does having a dummy column actually help me in getting the classes?

Comment: To whom it may concern, although this question prominently features R, the underlying issue is statistical. IMO, it should be considered on topic.

Comment: In "cubic cluster criterion" there is something called the "reference distribution" which is a uniformly sampled hypercube with axes aligned/scaled to the principal components of the data.  If you are randomly classifying your data, then you are more likely to fit this "reference distribution" than the fundamental "physics' of the data.  If the data is "clean enough" then you can use a hierarchical model to determine something about the "clusters" hidden in it.  This can lead you to some approximate classifications that are likely to be actual.

Comment: What is it that you ultimately want to achieve? Eg, are you trying to discover hidden 'groups' in the data, or some other kind of structure? What?

Comment: I want to find the outcome of the data. Can the random forest see a pattern in the data and give me a prediction that is close to the outcome? I guess closer to unsupervised learning.

Comment: Could you more specifically describe what it means to have "no outcomes"? On the face of it, that's an empty dataset, so what could one possibly do?

Comment: @whuber what I mean by no outcome is there is just the expression levels of the genes for each sample but we don't know if they have cancer or not. So the samples are not labeled.

Comment: at first glance this approach seems as promising as searching for water with a forked stick. The extracted proximity measure of the forest would still have some validity though, but I don't think it would be any more useful than a similarity based unsupervised method such as: kmeans, hirachial clustering etc.